# Number of "small" subsets to a "large" set

Tags: set-theory

For the following we assume the axiom of choice.
Let $X$ be a set of cardinality $l$ for some infinite cardinal number $l$, and let $p(X)$ be the number of subsets of $X$ that have cardinality strictly smaller than $l$.

Is it true that $|p(X)|=l$?

The notation is chosen with "$P(X)=$the (full) powerset of $X$" in mind

Comment: The subsets of $X$ of size $t$ form a collection of size $l^t$. So what you need is that $l^t=l$ for all $t<l$. This condition implies that $l$ is regular (so, $\aleph_\omega$ is a counterexample, as pointed out in an answer), but is in general strictly stronger. For instance, it is consistent that $\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take for example I to be $\aleph_{\omega}$.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I need a workaround.